# Adding childnode to childnode using treeview

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add child node to child node.

I use below code;

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("0");
treeView1.Nodes["0"].Nodes.Add("1");
treeView1.Nodes["1"].Nodes.Add("2");
treeView1.Nodes["2"].Nodes.Add("3");
treeView1.Nodes["3"].Nodes.Add("4");
treeView1.Nodes["1"].Nodes.Add("5");
```

What i want is this;

```
0
 1
  2
   3
    4
  5
```

However it always fail. It doesn' find the parent nodes. What should i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that the `Nodes` collection of the treeView1 control is not a list of all the nodes in the tree - it is only a list of the top level nodes.  What makes it hierarchical is that a tree node can contain a list of child nodes.  So, to get the tree structure you defined in your question, you will want to do something like this:

```
private void AddTreeNodes()
{
    // Create the root node.
    TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes.Add("0");

    // the root node has only one child node (1), so we will reuse the node object
    node = node.Nodes.Add("1");

    // Now, the node is the parent of two nodes (2 and 5).
    // We will want to keep track of node 2 because it has child nodes.
    TreeNode anotherNode = node.Nodes.Add("2");

    // Since node 5 doesn't have any child nodes, we don't need to keep track of it in this example.
    node.Nodes.Add("5");

    // Now, we need to make the child node of node 2. (Specifically, node 3).
    node = anotherNode.Nodes.Add("3");

    // And finally add the child node of node 3.
    node.Nodes.Add("4");
}
```

You could also do it like this:

```
private void AddTreeNodes()
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("0");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("1");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("2");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("5");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("3");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("4");
}
```

Now, I know that the code is ugly, but the main ideas to get from this are:

1. The `TreeView` control contains a List of `TreeNode` objects (`Nodes`).  This list is not a list of all nodes within the tree, just those that are the direct children of the control itself.
2. Any child nodes that exist under a parent node must be added to the parent node's list of `TreeNode` objects.
3. Every `TreeNode` object contains a list of `TreeNode` objects that are it's children.
4. When you add a `TreeNode` to another Node, or the `TreeView` control itself, a reference to the new `TreeNode` object is returned.
5. The Index of a `TreeNode` is it's index in relation to the list that it is within - not an index in relation to the entire hierarchy.
6. The `TreeNode` object has several properties that help with navigating the tree.  `PrevNode` and `NextNode` get the previous or next sibling tree node (if they exist). and `Parent` gets the parent `TreeNode` of the current node.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that you are using the `TreeNodeCollection.Add` method that [accepts a string value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esz34cwb(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the text of the node and not the key.  You then try to populate other nodes via a key.

Try the following instead:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("0", "0");
treeView1.Nodes["0"].Add("1", "1");
treeView1.Nodes["0"].Nodes["1"].Add("2", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `Nodes[string]` is looking for a `TreeNode` in *this* collection with the specified *key* (which is not the node's *text*).

`TreeNodeCollection.Add` returns the inserted `TreeNode`. So use this return value to add further child nodes:

```
TreeNode child = treeView1.Nodes.Add("0");
TreeNode child1 = child.Nodes.Add("1");
child1.Nodes.Add("2").Nodes.Add("3").Nodes.Add("4");
child1.Nodes.Add("5");
```